# How can show status from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **message**.

```
id | name   |  email         |  message |  status
-------------------------------------------------
1  | name1  |  n1@gmail.com  |  hello1  |  unread
-------------------------------------------------
3  | name2  |  n2@gmail.com  |  hello2  |  unread
-------------------------------------------------
7  | name1  |  n1@gmail.com  |  hello3  |  read
-------------------------------------------------
8  | name1  |  n1@gmail.com  |  hello4  |  read
-------------------------------------------------
9  | name2  |  n2@gmail.com  |  hello5  |  read
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to show status based on email.

**Ex:** For email `n1@gmail.com`

There are 1 unread and 2 read messages. So i want to show status=unread(1) for email `n1@gmail.com`

My output shoul be:

```
email         |  status
--------------------------
n1@gmail.com  |  unread(1)
--------------------------
```

My attempt is:

```
<?php
include"connection.php";
extract($_SESSION);
extract($_REQUEST);
$q2=mysql_query("select DISTINCT(email) from message where email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
while($r2=mysql_fetch_array($q2))
{
    extract($r2);
    $s1=mysql_query("select status from message where email='$email'");
    $no=mysql_num_rows($s1);
    echo $s1['status'];
    echo "unread("; 
    if($no['status']=='read') 
    { 
    echo "0"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    echo $no; 
    } 
    echo ") ";
}

?>
```

But it gives total number of rows. How can it possible? Please help!

Comment: I'm assuming `echo ") ?>` is a typo?

Comment: echo ")"; shows only )

Comment: `select status from message where email='$email' and status = 'unread'`?

Comment: Got no mysql here but something like `Select concat(status,'(', count(status),')') from message where email='$email' group by status` should do it

Comment: Oh thanx...It was so easy...but did not think about it...That was my fault..

Answer (score 0):

```
$s1=mysql_query("select status from message where email='$email'");
```

it will always give you total number of rows because you are fetching total messages no condition on status, you can try this

```
$s1=mysql_query("select status from message where email='$email' AND status='unread'");
$no=mysql_num_rows($s1);
if($no==0)
{
   $msg = 0;
}
else
{
    $msg=$no;
}
```

then you can output this

```
echo $msg;
```